# writing a ping test applet in powershell, cant tell if the function i am calling is actually doing anything

Tags: powershell

I have been writing this in conjunction with chatGPT actually as I wouldn't be able to do something like this on my own as I am a novice with PowerShell scripting.  I have a nice little GUI working that allows me to specify a few targets, a log file, and the interval I want and then runs a ping test when I hit the start button repeatedly to each target until I hit the stop button.  the ping tests run as background jobs and those jobs do seem to be being created and running but the log file isn't created and the debug stuff I put in to write some stuff to the console when the function runs doesn't show up so I am not convinced that the function is actually running. I will include the whole script here.  One heads up is that for now I have the name of my wifi interface hard coded which the script uses to populate a status line that shows the hostname, ip, etc of the machine the ping test is running on. if you dont change it to match your setup you may get an error if you try to run the code locally.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Define the GUI form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Ping Test"
$form.Width = 700
$form.Height = 500
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Define the form elements
$logLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$logLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$logLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$logLabel.Text = "Log file path:"
$form.Controls.Add($logLabel)

$logTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$logTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 30)
$logTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(430, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($logTextBox)

$browseButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$browseButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(450, 30)
$browseButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$browseButton.Text = "Browse..."
$form.Controls.Add($browseButton)

$sourceLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$sourceLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 60)
$sourceLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$sourceLabel.Text = "Source:"
$form.Controls.Add($sourceLabel)

$sourceTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$sourceTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 80)
$sourceTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 20)
$sourceTextBox.ReadOnly = $true
$hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$localIP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "Wi-Fi" | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress
$publicIP = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.ipify.org?format=text")
$sourceTextBox.Text = "Hostname: $env:COMPUTERNAME Local IP: $localIP Public IP: $publicIP"
$form.Controls.Add($sourceTextBox)

$targetsLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$targetsLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 110)
$targetsLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$targetsLabel.Text = "Targets:"
$form.Controls.Add($targetsLabel)

$targetsDataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$targetsDataGridView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 130)
$targetsDataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 200)
$targetsDataGridView.ColumnCount = 2
$targetsDataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Name"
$targetsDataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "IP Address"
$statusColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$statusColumn.Name = "Status"
$targetsDataGridView.Columns.Add($statusColumn)
$form.Controls.Add($targetsDataGridView)

$intervalLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$intervalLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 340)
$intervalLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$intervalLabel.Text = "Interval (seconds):"
$form.Controls.Add($intervalLabel)

$intervalTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$intervalTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 340)
$intervalTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$intervalTextBox.Text = "5"
$form.Controls.Add($intervalTextBox)

$statusLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$statusLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 370)
$statusLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$statusLabel.Text = "Status:"
$form.Controls.Add($statusLabel)

$startButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$startButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 420)
$startButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$startButton.Text = "Start"
$form.Controls.Add($startButton)

$stopButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$stopButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120, 420)
$stopButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$stopButton.Text = "Stop"
$stopButton.Enabled = $false
$form.Controls.Add($stopButton)

# Define the log file path
$logFilePath = ""

# Define the ping function
function Ping-Target {
    param($targetName, $targetIPAddress, $interval)
    Write-Host "Ping-Target function called for $targetName ($targetIPAddress)"
    while ($true) {
        Write-Host "Pinging $targetName ($targetIPAddress)..."
        $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $targetIPAddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $resultText = if ($pingResult) { "Success" } else { "Failure" }
        Write-Host "Ping result for $targetName ($targetIPAddress): $resultText"
        $logLine = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f (Get-Date -Format "ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), $env:COMPUTERNAME, $ip, $targetName, $targetIPAddress, $resultText
        Add-Content $logFilePath -Value $logLine
        $status = if ($pingResult) { "Success" } else { "Failure" }
        $targetsDataGridView.Rows | Where-Object { $_.Cells[1].Value -eq $targetIPAddress } | ForEach-Object { $_.Cells[2].Value = $status }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $interval
    }
}

# Define the event handlers
$browseButton.Add_Click({
    $logFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $logFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    $logFileDialog.Title = "Select a log file"
    if ($logFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $logTextBox.Text = $logFileDialog.FileName
    }
})

$startButton.Add_Click({
    # validate log file input
    $logFilePath = $logTextBox.Text
    if ($logFilePath -eq "") {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a log file.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }

    #validate interval input
    $interval = $intervalTextBox.Text
    if (-not [int]::TryParse($interval, [ref]$null) -or $interval -le 0) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please enter a positive whole number for the interval.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }
    Write-Host "Log file path: $logFilePath"
    # Get the targets from the DataGridView and start a ping job for each target
    $targets = @()
    foreach ($row in $targetsDataGridView.Rows) {
        if ($row.Cells[0].Value -ne $null -and $row.Cells[1].Value -ne $null) {
            $targetName = $row.Cells[0].Value
            $targetIPAddress = $row.Cells[1].Value
            $status = $row.Cells[2].Value
            $targets += [pscustomobject] @{
                Name = $targetName
                IPAddress = $targetIPAddress
                Status = $status
            }
        }
    }
        # validate minimum targets
    if ($targets.Count -eq 0) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please define at least one target to ping.", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    return
}

# Set the status label and disable the start button
    $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Running"
    $startButton.Enabled = $false
    $stopButton.Enabled = $true

    foreach ($target in $targets) {
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Ping-Target $using:target.Name $using:target.IPAddress $using:interval }
        Write-Host "Starting ping job for $($target.Name) ($($target.IPAddress))"
        if ($job.Error) {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("An error occurred while starting the ping test job: $($job.Error[0].Exception.Message)", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
            $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Stopped"
            $startButton.Enabled = $true
            $stopButton.Enabled = $false
            break
        }
    }

    # Write the current jobs to the console
    $jobs = Get-Job
    if (!$jobs.Error) {
        Write-Host "Background jobs started: $($jobs.Count)"
    }
})

$stopButton.Add_Click({
    Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force
    $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Stopped"
    $startButton.Enabled = $true
    $stopButton.Enabled = $false
})

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I have been adding in debug code to hoping to determine how much of the process is actually running but I don't get anything back into the console.  I dont know if maybe all the output is going to the console in use by the background job instead of the console that the script is running in?  I am just not familiar enough with coding in powershell to know how it works.  any way someone could take a look at what I have and give me some advice on why the function isnt being called if that is the case?  one other odd thing is that there is a random number 2 that gets written to the console when the GUI spawns and I cant figure out why.

Comment: PING uses the protocol ARP and you send an ARP Request and get back an ARP response.  The ARP response goes into you machines ARP table and stays for 30 to 60 minutes.  So to see if code is running you can examine the ARP table using cmd.exe >ARP -a.  So run before and after you script and see if values are added.

Comment: I have verified that the pings are not running by examining the network traffic from the machine I have been running this on.

Comment: I feel like what is happening is that the ping tests are being created as background jobs but they are never calling the ping-target function.  I just cant work out why

Comment: The Ping should be in the click event.  Or create an On Exit event to run code.  It just looks like the ping code is in wrong place.  The code needs to be in a method and you have the ping code just sitting "NO PLACE" in the form.

Comment: Please forgive me if this is stupid but I am quite a novice here.  I thought I had the ping code in a function and then the click event of the start button creates a background job for each defined target and the jobs call the function which runs the ping continuously.  then the stop button event kills the jobs which stops the pings.  is that not what's happening?

Comment: The code is after the event $startButton.Add_Click().  Are you familiar with c#.  The line $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Running" is at top of module in global space where you define global variables but it is outside an methods. For code to run it has to be in a function.  You can create  function and then call from a click event.

Comment: You have a form which is a class object.  The code that does the ping only gets executed one when the form is created.  The variable $targets is inside the click event and does not have any value outside the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the function wasnt executing.  I was making a syntax error in the part where I was spawning the background jobs and having them call the function.  I needed to change this line:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Ping-Target $using:target.Name $using:target.IPAddress $using:interval }
```

to this instead:

```
job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:Ping-Target} -ArgumentList $target.Name, $target.IPAddress, $interval, $logFilePath, $localIP, $publicIP
```

that allowed the function to run with all the relevant variables available.  as soon as I made that change my log file started populating with the data I wanted from the tests.  Thanks to everyone who took a look and offered some advice!